# array.find() return item and index

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of data, and I need to return the data from an item in the array, as well as the index of the result:

My code below returns the data, but not the index so I don't believe this is working correctly at all.

Can anyone advise how I can achieve what I am attempting to do below please?

```
const result = design.data().items.find((e, i, a, arg) => {
  if(e.id === this.props.match.params.item) {
    return {item:e, index: i}
  }
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) instead of the `find` method.

```
const { items } = design.data();
const id = items.findIndex((e) => e.id === this.props.match.params.item);
if (id !== -1) {
  return { item: items[id], index: id };
}
```

Comment: findIndex only returns the index, but I also need the data from find

Comment: I was assuming you could then use the index to retrieve the actual item from the list. Sorry, I should've explained that in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple find method, that uses [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). If the index is not `-1` (an item was found), it returns the item and the index:

```js
const findWithIndex = (arr, predicate) => {
  const index = arr.findIndex(predicate);
    
  return {
    item: index !== -1 ? arr[index] : null,
    index
  };
};

const arr = [{ id: 1}, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];

const result = findWithIndex(arr, ({ id }) => id === 2);

console.log(result);
```

Usage example with your code:

```
findwithIndex(design.data().items, e => this.props.match.params.item);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the index of the element. Then using the index you can get the element from the array

```
const items = design.data().items;
const index = items.findIndex(item => item.id === this.props.match.params.item);
console.log(index);  // gives index
console.log(items[index]);  // gives the element
```